# Hot Swap Fails in forge 1.8.9

Tags: intellij-idea, minecraft, minecraft-forge, minecraft-fabric

Ik this is an old version of forge and stuff but im making a mod for hypixel (basically u want to play on versions be4 1.9). Anyway, my hotswap feature in intelij stopped working for about a month. It is very annoying and demotivating :(. I've tried to fix it with ->
https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/78545-114-hot-swap-fails-in-idea/

but that does not seem to work and even makes it worse as the game doesnt even run and just output this ->

`java: Specified default obfuscation environment "named:intermediary" was not defined. This probably means your build configuration is out of date or a required service is missing

java: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/tree/MethodNode
org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode
`

I did exactly as was in the link's tutorial (at the end) but it did not work so... Can anyone help please?

BTW i know that to hot swap you cant change/add/remove variables that are not inside functions
(eg: public static int ...) so i am not doing that.

Comment: BTW here's the message that im getting from hot swap failing ->

Hot Swap failed Minecraft Client: schema change not implemented Minecraft Client: Operation not supported by VM

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean its just basic minecraft code like i have 150+ files and i don't really know which one to send to you since they are all like normal code could you please specify what you mean?

Here are my settings --

GRADLE JVM - azul 15
SDK - corretto 1.8 (Amazon)

And thats basically it

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the built in hot swap is not very good and does not work if you have mixins (i asked a few ppl and i think that that is the problem).

BUT DO NOT CLICK OFF THIS JUST YET!

I have found a REALLY helpful hot swap module that WORKS! here's the website for it -> https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14832-single-hotswap

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).